# Migrate data from one table to the other

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have two tables and I have to transfer data from one to the other.

**Table 1:** employees

```
home_address string
```

**Table 2** emp_address

```
address      string 
emp_id       int 
is_permanent bool
```

I need to migrate data from one to the other.

So I have only 2  conditions while inserting:

1. I cannot insert the address which has already been inserted into the **emp_address**  for that employee.
2. The ***is_permanent*** flag is set to true if no address has been inserted for the employee (i.e. if no single entry is present for the employee set is as true else false)

I cannot seem to get my head around how to I do this.

Comment: Is this MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: @KayanaHarley . . . Sample data and desired results would help.  It is not clear to me why you would want to store the address in two different tables; that violates the precepts of normalization, so you would typically want a good reason for doing so.  And there are is no `bool` data type in SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, i just added the tag because i thought if someone helped me in mysql i can convert it to mssql

Comment: Can you explain better the 2 conditions?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff As a user can have multiple addresses, I do not want to have all the different addresses in the same employees table

Comment: What's epn.number ?

Comment: @Barbaros Ozhan sorry i made a typo. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists` :

```
insert into emp_address (address,emp_id,is_permanent)
    select ea.address, e.id, IIF(ea.number IS NOT NULL,0,1)  
      from employees e
      left join dbo.emp_address ea 
        on e.id=ea.emp_id 
     where not exists ( select 0 
                           from dbo.emp_address 
                           where e.id = emp_id 
                             and e.home_address = address )
       and ea.address is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I also do not want to add null address into the emp_address table. I think this query inserts null data too

Comment: @KayanaHarley how can we know which addreses are null? What's the creteria ?

Comment: some employees in the employees table have home_address as null. I beleive null condition arises there

Comment: well after running just the query i am still getting  "cannot insert null error", as the address column has a not null constraint. I just checked the part from the select and there are some null address that which arrive for employees which do not have a home_address

Comment: @KayanaHarley therefore, most probably we need to add `and e.address is not null` to the bottom of the query. Btw, does employees table really have `address` column other than `home_address` ?

Comment: no it does not. It worked thank you very very much :). Saved my day

Comment: @KayanaHarley you're welcome. I got the issue by changing alias e to ea for address column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a new address with the appropriate `is_permanent` flag, you can use `not exists` twice:

```
insert into emp_address (address, emp_id, is_permanent)
    select e.address, e.id,
           (case when not exists (select 1
                                  from dbo.emp_address ea
                                  where ea.emp_id = a.id and
                                        ea.address = e.home_address and
                                        ea.is_permanent = 1
                                 )
                 then 1 else 0
             end)    
    from employees e 
    where not exists (select 1
                      from dbo.emp_address ea
                      where e.id = ea.emp_id and  e.home_address <> ea.address
                     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT EXISTS in the WHERE clause and a CASE statement to determine whether you will insert 0 or 1 in the column `is_permanent`.

```
insert into emp_address (address, emp_id, is_permanent)
select e.address, e.id,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from emp_address ea 
      where e.id = ea.emp_id and ea.is_permanent = 1       
    )  then 0
    else 1
  end
from employees e
where 
  e.home_address is not null
  and
  not exists (
    select 1 from emp_address ea
    where e.id = ea.emp_id and e.home_address = ea.address
  )
```